# List all users of AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm very new to AD B2C and I'm having trouble with the AD Graph API.

My goal is to list all the users registered to my AD. I would like to perform this only by HTTP requests.

So far, I found that I have to use this endpoint :

```
https://graph.windows.net/my_tenant.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6
```

My issue is that I cannot find where I can obtain the token used in the `Authorization` Header.

For now, i'm authentificating via this URL :

```
https://my_tenant.b2clogin.com/my_tenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=27fb84fe-4baf-4b6b-bfe7-f2d0638f2790
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost
&response_mode=query
&scope=27fb84fe-4baf-4b6b-bfe7-f2d0638f2790%20offline_access
&state=data
&p=B2C_1_SignUporSignIn
```

I obtain a code through my redirect_uri, and I send back this code to this endpoint to get a token :

```
https://my_tenant.b2clogin.com/my_tenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=b2c_1_signuporsignin
```

Following the docs here : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-access-tokens, I send these parameters :

```
grant_type:authorization_code
client_secret:my_secret
client_id:27fb84fe-4baf-4b6b-bfe7-f2d0638f2790
scope:openid
code:code
```

The problem is that I don't get a response like the one shown in the docs. I only get an `id_token`, `token_type`, `not_before`, `id_token_expires_in`, `profile_info`. However, the `id_token` seems to correspond to the `access_token` in the docs.

So the question is, is it this token which must be used in the Authorization header to send requests to the AD Graph API ?

Because if I use this token, I get the following error : `Authentication_ExpiredToken` - Your access token has expired. Please renew it before submitting the request.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You need to use client credentials grant + an app registered in the underlying AAD + use AAD login endpoint as shown in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Is it this token which must be used in the Authorization header to send requests to the AD Graph API ?***

Yeah for every resource access request either from `Azure Ad Graph` Or `Microsoft Graph API` you need to pass token that you received.

**Reason of your error: Authentication_ExpiredToken - Your access token has expired. Please renew it before submitting the request:**

I have tested and successfully reproduce error you encountered. See the screen shot:

[image]

**Possible Cause:**

1. Your token request endpoint may be wrong or you have received token
   for one tenant and trying to access other tenant resource. Make sure your token endpoint is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourB2CTenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token`
2. Check your resource: it should be `https://graph.windows.net/`

**Token Request Format:**

```
Request Endpoint URL: 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenantName.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token
```

Request Body

```
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:AppId
client_secret:AppSecret
resource:https://graph.windows.net/
```

See the Screen Shot below:

[image]

**B2C User Access Format:**

User List Request URL:

```
 https://graph.windows.net/YourTenantName.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6
```

See the screen shot:

[image]

**Point To Remember:**

You might encounter `Insufficient privilege error 401` in that case just assign following  permission.

**Permission From:** `Windows Azure Active Directory`

**Permission Name:** `Read all users' full profiles`

**Permission Type:** `DELEGATED PERMISSIONS`

See the screen shot:

[image]

This how you can get your azure B2C token and with that token access your user list.